# Python Looping help for input

Tags: python, loops

I was doing a practical in my school, just for the basics of Python for an upcoming test. The question is to make a simple fruit machine. Where if you get all three the same you win more money etc. The code is unfinished but i need help on - How do I loop it back to the Roll or quit input once it has already rolled?

My Code -

```
 print("Welcome to the Fruit Machine, to play type 'roll' or leave type 
 'quit'. You start with £1 and each go is 20p")
 print()
 import random
 reel1 = ['Cherry', 'Lemon', 'Bell', 'Star', 'Skull']
 reel2 = ['Cherry', 'Lemon', 'Bell', 'Star', 'Skull']
 reel3 = ['Cherry', 'Lemon', 'Bell', 'Star', 'Skull']
 credit = 1
 start = input("Enter Roll or Quit? ")
 if start == "quit":
   print("Your winnings are £" + str(credit))
 if start == "roll":
   newamount = (credit - 0.20)
 print("-20p")
 print("Credit now £" + str(newamount))
 print()
 print("------")
 print(random.choice(reel1))
 print("------")
 print(random.choice(reel2))
 print("------")
 print(random.choice(reel3))
 print("------")
 if random.choice(reel1) == random.choice(reel2):
  print("Yeah")
```

Comment: why do you use three reelX ?

Comment: The reel is supposed to be like the three symbols on a fruit machine when you spin it. it randomly chooses one from the list.

Comment: Oh, then I think you havn't finished the code. I'll post my code,tell me whether it's your intension.(Forgive my poor english...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
print("""Welcome to the Fruit Machine, to play type 'roll' or leave type'quit'.
You start with £1 and each go is 20p\n""")

reel = ['Cherry', 'Lemon', 'Bell', 'Star', 'Skull']
credit = 1

while credit > 0:
    # I suppose that you want to input the command every loop.
    start = input("\nEnter Roll or Quit? ")
    if start.lower() == "quit":
        print("Your winnings are £" + str(credit))
        break
    if start.lower() == "roll":
        # update the credit 
        credit = (credit - 0.20)
        print("-20p")
        print("Credit now £{:.2f}".format(credit))
        arr = [random.choice(reel) for i in range(3)]  # gen three machine results in list expression 
        print("Random choice result:{}, {}, {}".format(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]))
        if arr[0] == arr[1] and arr[1] == arr[2]:
            print("Yeah")
            # I think you should do some op on the credit here .
            # such as:
            # credit += xxx
```

Comment: When i run the code it says - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'roll' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, i'll debug it

Comment: I am not very good with Python, I am know just the basics. Still learning you see.

Comment: Yeah, I was a greenhand too.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's my pleasure. And I suggest you to digest it, and then rewrite it by yourself.